# c++ memory mess in arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

Why does this happen?

```
u_char macDst[6], macSrc[6], ipType[2]={0x88, 0x92};
u_char header[] = {0x04,0x00,0x20,0x00,...,};
const int len = sizeof(macDst) + sizeof(macSrc) + sizeof(header) + 2;
u_char* pck[len];

int j = 0, length = sizeof(macDst);
for (j; j < length; j++)
{
    pck[j] = &macDst[j];
}
length += sizeof(macSrc);

for (j; j < length; j++)
{
    pck[j] = &macSrc[j - sizeof(macDst)];
}

pck[j++] = &ipType[0];
pck[j++] = &ipType[1];

length += sizeof(header) + 2;

for (j; j < len; j++)
{
    pck[j] = &header[j - sizeof(macDst) - sizeof(macSrc)];
}
u_char testSend[170];

memcpy(testSend, *pck, sizeof(pck));
```

The var testSend only has macDst values (before initialized), while in the pointer I have all of them. If I copy them one by one, I get a good result:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 170; k++)
{
    testSend[k] = *pck[k];
}
```

Any idea??

Thanks!!

Edit:

This is a physic problem:

```
-----ooooooooo------------aaaa----bbbb----
- Null Data
```

When I make the pointers array I am doing this:

```
oooooooooaaaabbbb
```

But when I sent the packet and when I did the memcpy (or memmove) I was saying this: take this pointer and this amount of memory and copy them:

```
----|oooooooooo----------|----aaaaa----bbbb----
```

being the amount the sum of the 3 memory places.

Comment: `pck` is an array of *pointer* to `u_char`, which seems wrong to me. It would make more sense if it was an array of `u_char` and you copied all single bytes to it instead of the pointers, because sending a sequence of process-private pointers to somewhere else (especially over a network which I'm guessing you do) just makes no sense.

Comment: Your call to `memcpy` is wrong, you are copying part of your array of pointers into `testSend`, not the content pointed by the pointers.

Comment: Yes, this is for a network, but: Yes this has no sense, cos my idea was creating the arrays of headers independently and next to join their pointer in a pointers array. I get it, cos when I go over it, I see all of them. The problem may be this:
-----ooooooo--------------------------oooooooo--------ooooooooo
(- null)
(o data)

When I join them in the array, I can access to all of them sorted but, when I do that (memcpy), I am saying, take this pointer and copy this amount of memory: 170:
--|ooooooooo------------|------oooooo-------oooooooo
I am taking |these values|

Comment: "memory mess in arrays" - that's unfortunately common. Use `std::string` and `std::vector` instead, or even `std::array`.

Answer (score 0):

I find the code convoluted, and I would never write it this way. Still, the error here:

```
memcpy(testSend, *pck, sizeof(pck));
```

You are dereferencing `pck` - and point to the first element, which is a `char*`. This is what you copy using your memcpy. On the other hand, your hand-written loop does dereference the pointer before copying it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, this is SO formatting playing tricks on me. It used * i had after char to convert text to italics!

Answer (score 0):

Fill the `testSend` array directly:

```
u_char *p = testSend;
memcpy(p, macDst, sizeof(macDst)); p += sizeof(macDst);
memcpy(p, macSrc, sizeof(macSrc)); p += sizeof(macSrc);
memcpy(p, ipType, sizeof(ipType);  p += sizeof(ipType);
memcpy(p, header, sizeof(header));
```